# Intellisense does not recognize F# library from C# in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: f#, visual-studio-mac

Intellisense does not recognize my F# library from a C# project

Although the project compiles perfectly.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I took care to add the references to FLib in CMain.

[image]

F# code :

```
namespace FLib

module Say =
    let Hello name = "Hello " + name
```

Do you know why FLib is not recognized by Intellisense from Program.cs ?

---

Edit : Same problem when I try to use a C# library from a F# project

Comment: This is (still) a known limitation of Visual Studio (2017, haven't tried in 2019 yet). It's annoying, but as long as things compile I can live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue has been fixed and we are hoping to release the fix with the 8.0.5 release.

[From Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/538452/view.html)